# Media player with specific features

Tags: windows, media-player, chromecast, subtitles

The features I want the Media Player to have are:

- Seek bar video player like in YouTube
- Can go next and the previous video without closing the program and add a playlist
- Chromecast connect to TV
- Subtitles

Comment: Which one is more important: chromecast or next/previous video?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Chromecast. Why do you say that?

Comment: Have you test VLC Player? AFAIK it can feed to chromecast. But to play next file you should "import" all the files in directory. Or when you see the list you can drag and drop other file.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Yes I did use VLC, but It doesn't have seek bar pictures like youtube and Netflix.

Comment: Did you try [Kodi](https://kodi.tv/) or mxplayer?

Comment: I used Kodi but it doesn't have seekbar and MXplayer is only mobile device and doesn't have seekbar.